# Disabling service plans of Microsoft Dynamis Online Professional license through Graph API

Tags: dynamics-crm, msdn, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to disable the service plans of Microsoft Dynamic CRM online professional through **Active Directory Graph API**. It responsed with status 200 OK and when I check the response json , everything seems correct. All the service plans are with "capabilityStatus": "Deleted" values.

So it can be assumed that all the services are disabled successfully. But when I check the licenses of the user on Office 365 portal, the last one is not removed as shown per picture below.

Anyone has any idea on it why the service plan is not removed from the license on the portal although the return response status is "success" through the Graph API?

[image]

Thanks a lot for your suggestion and help.